# Checking values when div is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

So, I have the script below and it successfully checks the values of the inputs when I click on a div with `onclick="checkInputs()"` inside.

But when I click the div again, it doesn't run the code. would I have to put `return false;` after it?

```
function checkInputs() {
    if (document.getElementById("emailAdressInput").Value === "ADRESSHERE" && document.getElementById("passwordInput").Value === "PassHere")
    {
        document.getElementById("notifier").innerHTML = "Login Successful!";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("notifier").innerHTML = "Login Unsuccessful.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of element you should use `value` not `Value`

```
document.getElementById("passwordInput").value
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("passwordInput").Value;
```

**UPDATE**

Here is your working  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/suman_bogati/VZTA7/)

The strict operator  `===`  checks for type also, If you put `passHere` instead of `PassHere` it reurns false.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep this in mind. Any ideas as to why it doesn't run the function when I click on the div again?

Comment: @RyanCastle please have a look updated answer.

Comment: If answer solved your problem, please click on accepted answer.